# Mysqli multiple queries

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

Hi guys im having trouble with my sql queries. what im trying to do is the first query should insert and then with the inserted row i would like to select that and use in the third query for inserting to another table.

```
1) $sql .= "update player set money='".$total."' WHERE username = '" . $_SESSION['username'] . "';";

2) $uname = $_SESSION['username'];
$sql .= "INSERT INTO transaction(username, transactionType, postWinning, timeOfTransaction) VALUES('$uname', 'Buy', '$result', '$date')";

3) $sql = "Select transactionID from transaction order by transactionID DESC LIMIT 1";

4) $sql .= "INSERT INTO buySellDetail(transactionID, stockId, quantity, price) VALUES('$lastID', '$code', '$share', '$total');";
```

atm the 3rd and 4th queries are commented out in my code as it doesnt work. how am i suppose to write the third query? thank you

Comment: Hello. Before you continue, may you should take a look at http://bobby-tables.com and learn about SQL injection and how to prevent them. Right now, your code isn't safe at all and your database could be hacked in a few seconds without any problems.

Comment: If you are using mysqli_* the you can check this out http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php

Comment: As well as the above, study SQL transactions (the concept, not your table name) name so that you can ensure that you end up with consistent data. if you don't wrap all this in a single atomic transaction then if one of your inserts fails for any reason, then you'll end up with inconsistent data and it'll be very difficult to recover and know what to do to correct it. With a transaction, if something fails you can roll back the whole thing to the original state and handle the error as needed.

Comment: Also, `Select transactionID from transaction order by transactionID DESC LIMIT 1` does **not** guarantee you to get the last inserted transaction ID, especially if multiple users are using the system and inserting at the same time. Look at http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

Comment: Lastly, what does "doesn't work" mean? What error are you getting?